# Retrive all data in asp.net application 3.4 framework from sharepoint 2010

Tags: asp.net

My requirement is that I wish to access hole data in my local host web application from sharepoint 2010 
sharepoint is on another server and my web application is on another localhost.
on my desktop i have installed .net 2010 express and on machine there is no sharepoint installed
plz give me the step by step ans...

Comment: SO is really *not* the place to ask for tutorials. Did you try checking Microsoft's developer site? It's full of tutorials and samples on SharePoint and ASP.NET. Besides, you don't even show the code that produces this exception, don't mention which version of SharePoint you are using, you don't display the exception message and callstack. Besides, this message seems to be a server-side message so why are you seeing it client-side? Did you try to call the web services on the server instead of using the object model?

Comment: no one is here to help me???????????

Comment: Help with what? This question has changed so many times, now it's a generic administration question best asked at sharepoint.stackexchange.com. Technet describes the ways to copy a web application and **none of them** involves coding. Just backup the application from the administration site, restore it on a farm with the **same** Sharepoint version, and make sure you install any solutions as well. The procedures in Technet are the only supported (or sane) procedures to copy a web application. The reason you got no answers is that the original question was very poorly worded.

Comment: PS. editing one question to ask another guarantees you'll get no answers. You should post a new, properly worded question on the correct site, in this case, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com